# Compute the gcd of the following numbers.

Tags: number-theory

How to find the $\gcd(3+2i,1+i)$?

Working modulo the gcd we have: 
$$3=-2i,1=-i$$
$$\implies 3=(3-1)(-i)=(-2i+i)(-i)=1$$
$$\implies 2=0$$
$$\implies 3=0$$
$$\implies 1=3-2=0$$
So $\gcd(3+2i,1+i)=1.$

Is this correct?

Comment: Is $i$ an integer?

Comment: An easier way would be to write $\gcd(3+2i, 1+i) = \gcd(3+2i - 2(1+i), 1+i) = \gcd(1, 1+i) = 1$.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Presumably it's the $i$ from $i^2=-1$, making this a problem of $\gcd$ in the Gaussian integers. Not that it matters much, as the result is the same either way.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I have learned new tricks, but I would really appreciate it if someone could comment whether my answer is right or wrong.

Comment: @SuperMario  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method. The norms of your two Gaussian integers are $13$ and $2$, which are rational primes. Hence each is a prime. Since they are different primes, they are relatively prime.

Granted this is not as elementary as using the Euclidean algorithm or one of the tricks in the other answers.

Comment: That’s what I did when I saw the two g.integers given by OP. But of course this works in only one direction: try it on $2+i$ and $2-i$ and you get no useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bezout lemma since $$(3+2i)+(-2)(1+i)=1$$we have that $\gcd(3+2i,1+i)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Use that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a-kb)$ then

$$\gcd(3+2i,1+i)=\gcd(3+2i-2-2i,1+i)=\gcd(1,1+i)=1$$

Comment: Not really a hint cos you've given OP the whole answer! :)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I started for an hint but then I saw that the answer was already given by others! You are right I delete the "HINT" :)